# Sort array by date and time in ascending order

Tags: javascript, arrays, datetime

I have one array which is unsorted format.
i.e

```
var _dateArray = [
 { startTime : 'Sat Feb 21 2015 19:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)' ,endTime : ' Sat Feb 21 2015 20:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)' },
 { startTime : 'Sat Feb 21 2015 19:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)' ,endTime : ' Sat Feb 21 2015 20:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)' },
 { startTime : 'Sat Feb 21 2015 17:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)' ,endTime : ' Sat Feb 21 2015 19:15:00 GMT+0530 (IST)' },
 { startTime : 'Sat Feb 21 2015 20:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)' ,endTime : ' Sat Feb 21 2015 21:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)' },
 { startTime : 'Sat Feb 21 2015 16:30:00 GMT+0530 (IST)' ,endTime : ' Sat Feb 21 2015 16:45:00 GMT+0530 (IST)' },
 { startTime : 'Sat Feb 21 2015 16:30:00 GMT+0530 (IST)' ,endTime : ' Sat Feb 21 2015 17:15:00 GMT+0530 (IST)' },
];
```

i want to sort this array like this format

```
var _dateArray = [
     { startTime : 'Sat Feb 21 2015 16:30:00 GMT+0530 (IST)' ,endTime : ' Sat Feb 21 2015 16:45:00 GMT+0530 (IST)' },
     { startTime : 'Sat Feb 21 2015 16:30:00 GMT+0530 (IST)' ,endTime : ' Sat Feb 21 2015 17:15:00 GMT+0530 (IST)' },
     { startTime : 'Sat Feb 21 2015 17:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)' ,endTime : ' Sat Feb 21 2015 19:15:00 GMT+0530 (IST)' },
     { startTime : 'Sat Feb 21 2015 19:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)' ,endTime : ' Sat Feb 21 2015 20:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)' },
     { startTime : 'Sat Feb 21 2015 19:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)' ,endTime : ' Sat Feb 21 2015 20:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)' },
     { startTime : 'Sat Feb 21 2015 20:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)' ,endTime : ' Sat Feb 21 2015 21:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)' },
 ];
```

can you tell me how i can achieve this functionality?

Thanks.

Comment: please show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: I need to display this time as per sorting order on front page. Banana u did not understand my problem

Comment: i understood you very well, and i am already posting an answer to you. but next time please show some effort on your side and try to solve it yourself first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the JavaScript function `.sort()` with a custom comparator, in which you will parse the start dates and compare them.

the custom comparator is a function that receives 2 items, and returns negative/zero/positive value as per your custom comparison requirements. the `.sort()` function uses the provided comparator and uses it to compare the elements during sorting:

```js
var _dateArray = [{
    startTime: 'Sat Feb 21 2015 19:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)',
    endTime: ' Sat Feb 21 2015 20:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)'
}, {
    startTime: 'Sat Feb 21 2015 19:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)',
    endTime: ' Sat Feb 21 2015 20:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)'
}, {
    startTime: 'Sat Feb 21 2015 17:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)',
    endTime: ' Sat Feb 21 2015 19:15:00 GMT+0530 (IST)'
}, {
    startTime: 'Sat Feb 21 2015 20:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)',
    endTime: ' Sat Feb 21 2015 21:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)'
}, {
    startTime: 'Sat Feb 21 2015 16:30:00 GMT+0530 (IST)',
    endTime: ' Sat Feb 21 2015 16:45:00 GMT+0530 (IST)'
}, {
    startTime: 'Sat Feb 21 2015 16:30:00 GMT+0530 (IST)',
    endTime: ' Sat Feb 21 2015 17:15:00 GMT+0530 (IST)'
}];

//this is our comparator function
function DateComparator(dateAPair, dateBPair) {

    var DateA = new Date(dateAPair.startTime);
    var DateB = new Date(dateBPair.startTime);
    if (DateA < DateB) {
        return -1;
    } else if (DateA > DateB) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

console.log(_dateArray);
_dateArray.sort(DateComparator);
console.log(_dateArray);
```